# Timestamp remains same if datefmt is specified in logger settings file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a logger settings file (logger_settings.py) common for multiple python scripts where I have configured format and datefmt for loggers, ex:

```
logging_config = dict(
    version=1,
    formatters={
        'verbose': {
            'format': ("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s "
                       "[%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"),
            'datefmt': datetime.now().isoformat(sep='T',timespec='milliseconds')
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
            'datefmt': datetime.now().isoformat(sep='T',timespec='milliseconds')
        },
    },
    handlers={
        'tte-logger': {'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                       'formatter': 'verbose',
                       'level': logging.DEBUG,
                       'filename': '/home/abc/efg/logs/logtest_'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.log'},
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    loggers={
        'logger': {
            'handlers': ['logger', 'console'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG
        },
    }
)
```

and in script try.py :

```
from logger_settings import logging_config
from logging.config import dictConfig
from pathlib import Path

dictConfig(logging_config)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
```

all the loggers in try.py print the same timestamp in the log file:

```
**2024-01-04 03:18:18 INFO**     there
**2024-01-04 03:18:18 INFO**     here
**2024-01-04 03:18:18 INFO**     again
```

as per some suggestions I tried making datefmt as NONE, then this works, any idea why this happens, I would like the datefmt to be iso format

```
**2024-01-04 03:30:11,595 INFO**     there
**2024-01-04 03:30:11,598 INFO**     here
**2024-01-04 03:30:11,603 INFO**     again
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a *format string* (like `'%Y-%m-%d...'`) for `datefmt`, not a *formatted date*.

Comment: I have tried that as well , with 'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" still same timestamp   2024-01-04T03:41:44-0500 INFO    
2024-01-04T03:41:44-0500 INFO     
2024-01-04T03:41:44-0500 INFO

Answer (score 0):

```
            'format': ("%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s "
                       "[%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"),
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

this solved my issue.